# R rvest connect with local host

Tags: r, localhost, rvest

I am creating a way to read in SPSS labels into R.  Using library(sjPlot),  view_spss(df, useViewer = FALSE) I can create a local html page such as http://localhost:11773/session/file1e0c67270a5.html that shows a nice table with columns for the variable names and the labels I am looking for.

Now I want to use rvest to scrape it but when I start with a command such as `page <- rvest::html("http://localhost:11773/session/file1e0c67270a5.html")` R just seems to get stuck.

I've tried searching for "connect with local host" but I can't seem to find any questions or answers related to the R package.

Comment: You should mention which package you are using for `view_spss` .

Comment: okay I added it to the question

Comment: I can reproduce your problem.It seems surprising because according to the help file, the input can also be local file.

Comment: See the haven package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your specific question as I think the reason is that R spins up a non-persistent process to serve that HTML view of your data. But your approach seems quite round-a-bout to just get to variable labels.  This is a general way that works quite well:

```
library(foreign)
d <- read.spss("your_data.sav", use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame=FALSE)
var_labels <- attr(d, "variable.labels")

##  To access the label of a variable named 'var_name':
var_labels[["var_name"]]
```

Where `d` results in a list of data, and `var_labels` is a named list of labels keyed by variable/column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get variable and/or value label of SPSS-imported data, you can use `get_val_labels` and `get_var_labels` of the [sjmisc-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjmisc/index.html).

See examples [here](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/datainit/). Both functions accept either a single variable (vector) or a data frame and return the associated variable and value labels. See also [this blog post](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/sjmisc-package-for-working-with-labelled-data-rstats/).

The sjmisc-Package supports data frames imported both with the haven- or foreign-package.